# How to listen to console commnads in android app?

Tags: android, adb

I want to send command to my app throuh usb cable. I think i should use adb for it, but i dont know how to listen to this commands. Is it possible? Something like
readLine()
method

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: firstly i want to read text and print it in toast.